# Is IMultiValueConverter Available for UWP

Tags: wpf, uwp, imultivalueconverter

I am converting a `WPF` to `UWP` and it uses a number of `IMultiValueConverters`. I can't find any reference for `IMultiValueConverter`.  Is it available in `UWP`? If not, if there an alternative?

Answer (score 3):

A very simple method for binding to multiple values is to use [x:Bind with a function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/function-bindings). For example,

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind local:Helper.FormatName(Id, Name)}" />
```

or

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind local:Helper.FormatTotal(ViewModel.SelectedWidget.Cost, ViewModel.Quantity, ViewModel.Bundles)}" />
```

In both of these examples the function is a static function, but the function can also be defined in the code behind or as part of the view model.

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind CalculateResult(ViewModel.Widget, ViewModel.Foo)}" />
```

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.FormatResult(ViewModel.Widget, ViewModel.Foo)}" />
```

Rather than passing individual values, you can pass a single object that contains multiple properties.

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind local:Helper.FormatResult(ViewModel.Widget)}" />
```

Function binding is very flexible and can often be used in place of a converter, creating simpler, more readable code.

```
<TextBlock Background="{x:Bind local:Helper.GetColor(ViewModel.Widget)}" />
```

Function binding can also be used with two way bindings by adding a BindBack function.

```
<TextBox Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.FormatWidget(ViewModel.Widget), BindBack=ViewModel.UpdateWidget}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no multiple converter in UWP.

Without Multiple Converter, you can bind to a single property in the ViewModel.

1 That single property should take into account multiple properties from the view model.

Let's call them source properties

2 If any any change is made to a source property, it should raise a PropertyChanged event on the single property.

Regards

Comment: What if you have a `ListView` whose `ItemsSource` is bound to a `Stuff` property on my VM and I want to say change the `Foreground` color based no an item in the collection?  I don't want my VM exposing color information (normally we would pass in the color from the XAML side into the converter)

Comment: You re right. The VM should not expose Color information. But binding to a VM property and using a Converter that can be parameterized with the ConverterParameter on the binding, or a property of the converter would be decent for me.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very good alternative for this. In the Cimbalino toolkit ( open source on github ) there is a MultiBind behaviour that has been ported to UWP

Details: https://www.pedrolamas.com/2013/05/17/cimbalino-windows-phone-toolkit-multibindingbehavior/
Toolkit code: https://github.com/Cimbalino/Cimbalino-Toolkit

It's also available as nuget, I personally create every UWP app with it, because it has so many great features

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks